# Ionic 2 "Error: Missing deploy plugin: `ionic-plugin-deploy`"

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-cloud

When I try and make any calls to the Ionic Cloud Deploy service within my app I get the following error message in my browser. This has only started happening recently and the app runs fine on a real device.

What could the cause be? I have the plugin installed, it is referenced in the config.xml. I have also tried removing the plugin, removing all platforms and then adding everything back but without luck. I even see this error when following the Ionic docs in a brand new project.

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Missing deploy plugin: `ionic-plugin-deploy` Error: Missing deploy plugin: `ionic-plugin-deploy` at Object.
<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:58591:17) at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30) at Object.
<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:59389:73) at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30) at Object. 
<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:57303:10) at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30) at Object.
<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:102834:79) at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30) at Object.
<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:91442:73) at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
```

Answer (score 8):

The error looks like you are running your code in the browser (ionic serve) and not on an actual device or simulator.

However, ionic-plugin-deploy only works on devices. If you work on another part of your app using the browser, you can ignore the error(s). If you want to debug your "deploy" code, you need to use a device.

If you want to disable dependent code from being executed, you can use [platform.is('cordova')](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/) to check whether you are on a real device or not.